# how do I filter table rows with specific values in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to be able to get a count of all rows checked where a cell has a specific value. So if given the below table, the user checks the checkbox next to row 1, I would get the following.

bonus rows selected = 1
base rows selected = 0

if I check the box next to row 2 I would get the following values

bonus rows selected = 2
base rows selected = 0

and if I uncheck the 2nd row, and check the third, I would get...

bonus rows selected = 1
base rows selected = 1

I can get the total number of rows selected in this way...

```
$(function(){
var $ck = $('input[type=checkbox]');
    $ck.filter(':checked').length;
)};
```

Can I chain selectors together somehow? This doesn't work, but is what I thought of...

```
m1 = $ck.filter(':checked')
               .parents('tr:first')
               .filter('.type')
               .text('Bonus')
               .length;
alert(m1); // returns 0
```

Here's a sample table

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Bonus</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class=".points">10</td>
        <td class=".type">Bonus</td>
        <td class=".chkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=".points">20</td>
        <td class=".type">Bonus</td>
        <td class=".chkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=".points">10</td>
        <td class=".type">Base</td>
        <td class=".chkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=".points">20</td>
        <td class=".type">Base</td>
        <td class=".chkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: why would you name your classes with a trailing dot?

Comment: Use `class="ClassName"`, without dot and use dot when you are using in jQuery like `$('.ClassName')`.

Comment: To expand on balexandre's comment, when you are declaring the class name, you do not have the dot at the beginning. That is only used as a jQuery selector on the class as you have above. Having it inside the class='points' will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
var chk=$('td.chkbox input:checkbox');
chk.on('change', function(){
    var checked=chk.filter(':checked');
    var bonus=0, base=0;
        checked.filter(function(){ 
        bonus+=$(this).closest('tr').find('td.type:contains("Bonus")').length;
        base+=$(this).closest('tr').find('td.type:contains("Base")').length;
    });
    $('div#result').html('Bonus rows selected = '+bonus+' Base rows selected = '+base);
});
```

Also notice `class=".className"` should be `class="className"`.

[**An Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJ3C/).

Comment: Thank you! The class=".ClassName" was a typo. I'm sorry for the confusion. Appreciate the fiddle example too!